# Inheritance: Value being inherited changes

Tags: c++, loops, class, inheritance

I am trying to write the snake game inside c++ and I am required to use inheritance (To be honest, I am not sure if my understanding of inheritance is even correct). I have two classes:

```
class gameInfo
class playSnake
```

inside gameInfo, is a function that is called by main to set a value of length and width (pseudo code):

```
class gameInfo{
    int playFieldWidth;
    int playFieldHeight;
    void getPlayFieldDimensions(){
        cout << "How big do you want to play field to be?\n";
        cout << "Width: ";
        cin >> playFieldWidth;
        cout << "Height: "; 
        cin >> playFieldHeight
    }
}

class play: public gameInfo {
    void setPlayField() {
        cout << playFieldWidth; // if I enter 10, returns -858993460. 
        //loop will print nothing.
        for (int row = 0; row < playFieldHeight; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < playFieldWidth; col++) {
                if (row = 0 || row == playFieldWidth - 1) {
                    cout << "*";
                } else  if (col == 0 || col == playFieldWidth - 1) {
                    cout << "*";
                } else {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            } cout << endl;
        }
    }

main () {
    playSnake play;
    gameInfo info;

    info.getPlayFieldDimensions();
    cout << info.playFieldWidth; // if I enter 10, returns as 10.
    play.setPlayField();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

The problem is, inside setPlayField(), width and height have a stored value of some super long negative number, not what was assigned.

Any help would be great. I tried looking this up but found nothing similar or helpful (imo). Thanks!

Comment: We like Minimal, but Minimal is useless without Complete. From the information provided the best we can say with any certainty is you have a bug. But if you build yourself a [mcve] to add to the question, odds are good you can delete the question as crafting a good MCVE almost always reveals the bug and its solution to you.

Comment: Impossible to help without knowing what `getPlayFieldDimensions` and `setPlayField` do. More info here: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: updated, sorry! @acraig5075

Comment: I don't see `playFieldWidth` and `playFieldHeight` declared there...? Assuming it's actually `width` and `height`. You probably didn't understand inheritance. `play` and `info` are two different objects now. Initializing variables of the `info` object won't initialize these in the `play`.

Comment: Objects `play` and `info` are two different objects that know nothing about each other. You want just one `PlaySnake` instance because that already is-a `GameInfo` object.

Comment: Is "play" the name of the class or the name of an instance?

Comment: Maybe I am thinking of polymorphism @user3366592 I read it in the book polymorphism & inheritance and it declared it like this, and accessed it. also, I declared them properly (they already were in my code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of inheritance is to define a class, that has some members (data, methods...) and then define a second class that inherits from the first and adds some of stuff of its own. In your case, you define `gameInfo`, it stores two values and has a method that lets you input those values. Then you define the class `play` that inherits from `gameInfo`. An instance of class `play` would now have 2 integers (both inherited) and 2 methods (1 inherited and 1 specific to `play`). So now, you never need to make an instance of `gameInfo`, you can just use `play` (you are of course free to make an instance of `gameInfo` should you desire, but it is not necessary in this case):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std; //Avoid this if possible (in general). 

class gameInfo{
    public:
    int playFieldWidth;
    int playFieldHeight;
    void getPlayFieldDimensions(){
        cout << "How big do you want to play field to be?\n";
        cout << "Width: ";
        cin >> playFieldWidth;
        cout << "Height: "; 
        cin >> playFieldHeight;
    }
};

class play: public gameInfo {
    public:
    void setPlayField() {
        cout << playFieldWidth;
        for (int row = 0; row < playFieldHeight; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < playFieldWidth; col++) {
                if (row == 0 || row == playFieldWidth - 1) {
                    cout << "*";
                } else  if (col == 0 || col == playFieldWidth - 1) {
                    cout << "*";
                } else {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            } cout << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main () {
    play playSnake;
    playSnake.getPlayFieldDimensions();
    cout << playSnake.playFieldWidth;
    playSnake.setPlayField();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Something like this should work (note I renamed the things in `main()` properly, your example had a typo. I also made everything public for the time being, so as to avoid complicating things further.

Comment: It worked! playFieldHeight inside of setPlayField() does indeed hold 10. Can you explain to me why I needed to call the function from playSnake.setPlayField()?

Comment: Each instance has it's own data, I can make `play a, b, c;` and if I store something in `a`, then the other two don't have that data. It's the same here, you can make `gameInfo a;` and `play b;`, if you store something in `a`, then `b` doesn't hold that data. You define what a class has, and then the other class inherits, that just means that instances of that class will have the same set of members (i.e. 2 ints and 2 methods), but that doesn't mean the instances are linked in any way.

Comment: That helped a lot! But what if I want to pull over information, such as an int, or use a function from class gameInfo in class play?

Comment: You can use the functions in `play`, it has them all. In the example above we used `playSnake.getPlayFieldDimensions();`, which was defined in `gameInfo` and inherited by `play`. I think you might be confusing a class and an instance of a class.

Comment: You said the values of one int has two values as it is instanced in both the class play and class gameInfo right? What if say I wanted to use the value stored in gameInfo's playFieldHeight inside of the play class? Inherited means it, being play, can use it, being gameInfo's initialized variables, but it doesn't mean they actually linked beyond that, such as sharing int values. (sorry for all the questions, im doing an online course and instruction on this topic is minimal)